# How to get the status of an entire row or coloumn of objects is a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, row

So i understand how to get the status of a specific object in.

```
somearray = new array[10][10]
```

the objects stored in this array are a switch and can either be on

```
(boolean status = true)
```

or off

```
 (status = false).
```

lets say

```
somearray[3][4].status() would = false
```

that's fine and i am happy with that.

what i want to know is how to check.

```
if(      // that each object in a full Row or a full column are all on) {
         //store that said row or coloumn details until finished checking all other rows and columns.
         //Then using the stored variable turn that whole row/s and or column/s off  }
```

i understand i can loop through every element in the array but how do i define if it as part of a full row/coloumn

thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: can you reform this sentence for me: "how do i define if it as part of a full row/coloumn", it's a bit unclear what you want ?

Comment: so i can check each individual status of each element in the array but how do i "identify" it as part of a particular row when i store in into a variable

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 stream api:

```
boolean oneFalseCell = Arrays.asList(somearray[0])
  .stream()
  .anyMatch(sw -> sw.status() == false);
```

oneFalseCell will be true if there is at least one cell in the row that is false, hence:

```
boolean rowStatus = !oneFalseCell;
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont provide your class, but it is most likely that you cant, what you can do is something like :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<somearray.length ; i++){

    boolean thisRowStatus= true;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < somearray[i].length ; j++)
        if(somearray[i][j].status() == false)
            thisRowStatus= false;

    if( thisRowStatus) { 
        //  do whatever you want with row number i
    }

}
```